# MySQL Insert on first table and update on 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into table_1 and then insert on second table if the new inserted ID not available on 2nd table if available then update it. Bellow is my code please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
    $name='Name';
    $pass='Passsword';
    $rid='FR200000';


    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_1 (id,name,pass) VALUES('".$rid."','".$name."','".$pass."')";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$res){
        echo'Failed to insert';

    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM site_settings WHERE id = '".$rid."'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
       $get_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

        if (!$get_id==$rid){
            $site_url = 'www.example.com';
            $site_email ='example@mysite.com';

            $sql = "INSERT INTO site_settings (id,site_url,site_email) VALUES('".$rid."','".$site_url."','".$site_email."')";
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
                if(!$res) return 1;
            return 99;
            }
        if ($get_id==$rid){

            $sql = "UPDATE site_settings SET site_url = '" . $site_url . "', site_email = '" . $site_email . "' WHERE ID = '".$rid."'";     
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
                if(!$res) return 1;
            return 99;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are not fetching data form select query!!  Need to fetch data form select query then use `if (!$get_id==$rid){`

Comment: @Saty I've update my question above please check it is ok or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)**

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM site_settings WHERE id = '".$rid."'";
        $get_id = mysql_query($sql);
```

You will not compare directly result set with `$rid`

```
if (!$get_id==$rid){
```

You need to fetch data first

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$get_id=$row['id'];// fetch data
```

Then compare

```
if (!$get_id==$rid){
// YOUR code
```

> NOTE:- mysql is  deprecated instead use mysqli OR PDO